# How to filter by max date inside groupBy in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, filter, group-by

I have data frame in PySpark with numeric field "value", date field "date" and year of date field "date_year". I would like to keep inside each "date_year" field only one row with max date.

Here is the snippet

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

df_orders = df_orders \
    .groupBy("company_id", "date_year") \
    .filter(f.col("date") == f.max(f.col("date")))
```

So, each company will have one max date per each year only.

This code unfortunately not works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rank the dates in desc order per `company_id` and `date_year` then `filter` the rows where rank is `1`

```
W = Window.partitionBy('company_id', 'date_year').orderBy(F.col('date').desc())
result = df.withColumn('rank', F.dense_rank().over(W)).filter('rank = 1')
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if i uderstand your case. If it is not what you are looking for please add some sample input/output so maybe it will be easier to understand

For this moment i tried to use window function to resolve your issue:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import datetime

data = [
    {"company_id": 1, "value": 3004, "date": datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 1), "date_year": 2020},
    {"company_id": 1, "value": 3004, "date": datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 17), "date_year": 2020},
    {"company_id": 1, "value": 3004, "date": datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 27), "date_year": 2020}
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("company_id", "date_year").orderBy(F.col("date").desc())

dfWithRowNumber = df.withColumn("row_number", F.row_number().over(windowSpec))
dfWithRowNumber.filter((F.col("row_number") == F.lit(1))).drop("row_number").show()
```

Output is

```
+----------+-------------------+---------+-----+
|company_id|               date|date_year|value|
+----------+-------------------+---------+-----+
|         1|2020-07-27 00:00:00|     2020| 3004|
+----------+-------------------+---------+-----+
```